# In real terms, how much faster is a production tier Heroku database than the starter database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

A basic production level database in Heroku implements a 400Mb cache. I have a production site running 2 dynos and a worker which is pretty heavy on reads and writes. The database is the bottleneck in my app.

A write to the database will invalidate many queries, as searches are performed across the database.

My question is, given the large jump in price between the $9 starter and $50 first level production database, would migrating be likely to give a significant performance improvement?

Comment: um the saying "Nothing in life is free" comes to mind, so what do you expect for free...of course your going to see an improvement if you pay..And speaking from experience the difference is VERY noticeable

Comment: We're currently on the $9 starter tier with 2 dynos and 1 worker. The site is slow, but budget is tight so I want to upgrade wisely. "Very noticable" sounds good.

Comment: When you say "very noticable" though, do you have any stats from personal experience? Are we talking 5%, or 50%. I know it's going to vary widely between use cases.

Comment: well without any exact figures to hand i cant give you a definitive answer, though i would say in my case a 40% increase, biggest things i have noticed have been quicker rendering time of pages, queries seem to load faster, generally a much better experience when using the site, hope that helps

Comment: you could always look at AWS? or invest in your own VPS, I can confidently recommend Heart Internet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24196/discussion-between-superluminary-and-richlewis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Faster" is an odd metric here. This implies something like CPU, but CPU isn't always a huge factor in databases, especially if you're not doing heavy writes. You Basic database has 0mb of cache – every query hits disk. Even a 400mb cache will seem amazing compared to this. Examine your approximate dataset size; a general rule of thumb is for your dataset to fit into cache. Postgres will manage this cache itself, and optimize for the most referenced data.

Ultimately, Heroku Postgres doesn't sell raw performance. The benefits of the Production-tier are multiple, but to name a few: In-memory Cache, Fork/Follow support, 500 available connections, 99.95% expected uptime.

You will definitely see performance boost in upgrading to a Production-tier plan, however it's near impossible to claim it to be "3x faster" or similar, as this is dependent on how you're using the database.

Comment: Faster as in real world time to execute a query. I just took the plunge and the response time is down by approximately 70%. It's a big win!

Comment: Probably a cache boost right there, glad things improved for you! Check out this heroku cli plugin: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras it can give you some insight to cache and index usage

Answer (score 2):

It sure is a steep step, so the question really is how bad is the bottleneck? It will cost you 40 dollar extra, but once your app runs smooth again it could also mean more revenue. Of course you could also consider other hosting services, but personally I like Heroku the best (albeit cheaper options are available). Besides, you are already familiar with Heroku. There is some more information on Heroku devcenter, regarding their different plans:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans:

> Production plans
>
> Non-production applications, or applications with minimal data storage, performance or availability requirements can choose between one of the two starter tier plans, dev and basic, depending on row requirements. However, production applications, or apps that require the features of a production tier database plan, have a variety of plans to choose from. These plans vary primarily by the size of their in-memory data cache.
>
> Cache size
>
> Each production tier plan’s cache size constitutes the total amount of RAM given to Postgres. While a small amount of RAM is used for managing each connection and other tasks, Postgres will take advantage of almost all this RAM for its cache.
>
> Postgres constantly manages the cache of your data: rows you’ve written, indexes you’ve made, and metadata Postgres keeps. When the data needed for a query is entirely in that cache, performance is very fast. Queries made from cached data are often 100-1000x faster than from the full data set.
>
> Well engineered, high performance web applications will have 99% or more of their queries be served from cache.
>
> Conversely, having to fall back to disk is at least an order of magnitude slower. Additionally, columns with large data types (e.g. large text columns) are stored out-of-line via TOAST, and accessing large amounts of TOASTed data can be slow.